# J48 algorithm in weka algorithm or flowchart steps

Tags: algorithm, flowchart, j48

I am new in the machine learning area. please, I was wondering if you could provide me with algorithm or flowchart steps for J48.
note: I am using the default setting in weka.
thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

J48 is based on Quinlan's [C4.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5_algorithm).